# Is using the Keychain from Apple a type of encryption?

Tags: ios, encryption

I am on the point to upload a binary to be approved (or not, you never know). I have done this a couple of times so no big deal, but this time it is a little bit different.

On the last page they ask about the encryption stuff. I normally answer no, but this time I have implemented the Keychain from Apple. Not the same methods, but something like this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

So now, I am a little confused in if I am using an encryption or not? I only use the above, no other encryption or whatever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Ok, so first I disagree, but what would be a good place then?

Comment: The Apple Developer forums.

Comment: Keychains are encrypted but they comply with rules.

Comment: So yes for the first question "Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)" And yes for the second question "Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?".

Comment: For the final word check the EAR [Export Administration Regulation](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/regulations/export-administration-regulations-ear). Probsbly Category 5 Part 2 - Information Security.

Comment: I doubt that there will be an answer in the The Apple Developer forums from an Apple employee. Another is the apple-cdsa list but the last I knew it was a closed list one must request to approval join in an effort to avoid spam. But I would be surprised if legal advice was given from either of them.